# I can't find a file I moved to USB drive

Tags: usb

I downloaded a short video, then wrote:

```
sudo mv /home/myname/Downloads/m.mp4 /dev/sdb1
```

the video disappeared completely. It's not in the USB drive. I searched for it by writing:

```
find / m.mp4 
find m.mp4
```

But it's nowhere to be found.I keep getting

```
find: ‘m.mp4’: No such file or directory
```

The USB is mounted and accessible. The video is no longer in Downloads.

Sudodus, thank you. I still don't get it fully but I understand I should've used the mount point. I used it and it worked, like magic. Nothing was erased from the USB, so I am not sure why you apologized. How would you know what the mount point is? I found it in Gparted. And what does this mean, from Gparted:

```
init :: non DOS media
Cannot initialize '::'
mlabel: Cannot initialize drive

init :: non DOS media
Cannot initialize '::'
```

The output when I wrote `sudo ls -l /dev/sdb1` is

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 moe moe 23362068 Jul  2 15:44 /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Next time remember that `/dev/sdb1` should be `mount`ed, not treated as a way to put files on the device. However Ubuntu and most other distros will mount things for you automatically, e.g. at `/media/<username>/xyz`

Comment: As an aside, your find command is incorrect; it should be `find / -iname 'm.mp4'`. Also using `file /dev/sdb1` would show that it is a MP4 file, not a special device.

Answer (score 30):

Your file is still there. It's just now named `/dev/sdb1` and has replaced the device special node that would otherwise be used to mount your USB disk.

You can recover it by moving it back to somewhere else, for example:

```
sudo mv /dev/sdb1 /home/myname/Downloads/m.mp4
```

Don't overwrite files in `/dev` as these are not normal files, but special markers which give the OS raw access to certain hardware devices. Your use of `sudo mv` destroyed the device special node `/dev/sdb1` and replaced it with your video file.

After you move the video back to where it came from, eject and reinsert your USB stick, and you can write files to it via its mount point (typically `/run/media/yourusername/USBSTICKNAME` but you can run the command `mount` to see where it was actually mounted). Linux will recreate the device special `/dev/sdb1` if necessary when you reinsert the USB stick.

Also note that if your USB stick was correctly mounted by the system, its files should be writable by your username, and you should not need to use `sudo` to move files to or from it.

Comment: Also if you didn't use `sudo` then the computer wouldn't have let you do this dumb thing.

Comment: @user253751 I think the use of `sudo` was due to a failed attempt to move the file to the USB with `mv ... /dev/sdb1` (no `sudo`). It probably gave an error, like, "Permission denied". The general advice would be that any 'mv` that gives a permission denied error is an `mv` you want to analize before slapping `sudo` to it.

Comment: As much as it's not part of what the question is asking, I think it would be really useful for this answer to include a brief reminder that the commands in the post probably should never have been run with `sudo`.

Comment: @DavidZ I already said this scenario does not require `sudo`!

Comment: Ah, somehow I missed that part, sorry! Though FWIW I would favor a stronger statement, not just "you shouldn't have to use sudo" but rather "you should not be using sudo" or something along those lines.

Answer (score 4):

`lsblk` command could be used to find out your mount point:

```
$ lsblk | grep -v loop
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 221.6G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 232.9G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 232.9G  0 part /home
```

All devices in `/dev/` folder are recreated during OS start. You could see it by `ls -ailh /dev/` command and in case if some device have been reattached.

If you'll have a deal with Android device, you could find your device storages in `/var/run/user/1000/gvfs` folder, where `1000` is `uid` of your user.

```
$ ls /var/run/user/1000/gvfs
gvfs/      gvfs-burn/ 
user@ubuntu:~$ cd /var/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp\:host\=Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_3951d46a7d27/
user@ubuntu:/var/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_3951d46a7d27$ ls
 disk  'Internal shared storage'
user@ubuntu:/var/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=Xiaomi_Redmi_6A_3951d46a7d27$ echo $UID
1000
```

Devices also could be mount automatically into `/media/$USER` or `/mnt` folders.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of usb-port. Sometimes usb-ports of computers or notebooks are not fully mounted by driver. So you could try :

> umount /dev/sdb1

or

> sudo umount /dev/sdb1

then

> mount /dev/sdb1

or

> sudo mount /dev/sdb1

If this does not help - plug-out and plug-in again the usb-drive (usb-stick?).
Then repeat umount and mount again like written above.

When you want to move or to copy files as sudo, then you need to mount as sudo too.

Before you move or copy files not as sudo, instead as normal user - then you can umount or mount as normal user too. It depends on the files, which file-permissions they have.